# Issue with UIViewController in iPad Universal App

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow, universal-binary

I recently upgraded my iPhone app to a universal binary. I have 2 view controllers and nibs, one for the iPhone and one iPad. I scaled up the *iPad UI*  and created the exact same connections in *IB*.

However, I get this error:

`-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:]` loaded the "HomeScreen_iPad" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

I can say for a fact that the view outlet is indeed set. I have gone through every connection and init method. I cannot figure out why the *iPhone version* loads and it won't on iPad.

I am using the simulator and if I don't get this error in the debugger, I get a white screen. Changing any color properties of `UIWindow` has no effect.

If anyone can help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you distinguishing between the iPhone/iPad app?  Please post your App Delegate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Info.plist file. Have you added an entry for "Initial NIB (iPad)"?

Comment: I forgot I asked this question. Yes, your answer was the right one. Thanks for posting.